# C# using a return variable instead of a global variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, global-variables, return-value

Please note I am using Visual Studio 2015 to create an Excel VSTO. I have a whole host of questions regarding global variables. For the most part I have been trying to avoid them (because "globals are bad"), but by the same respect I have also seen people say using globals are not bad if you use them properly.

Assume the following class structure -

```
 1    public class ribbon {  //Class containing Ribbon button to activate
 2        private void button_click(){
 3            Globals.ThisAddIn.openUI();
 4        }
 5    }
 6    
 7    public class formClass {  //Class containing the user  form that will be used
 8        private void button_click(){
 9            Globals.ThisAddIn.setProperties(this.field1.Value, this.field2.Value);
10            Globals.ThisAddIn.runFunction();
11        }
12    }
13    
14    public class ThisAddIn {
15        struct someProperties {
16            public string foo;
17            public string bar;
18        }
19    
20        someProperties ps = new someProperties();
21        formClass ui = new formClass();
22    
23        public void openUI(){
24            ui.showDialog();
25        }
26    
27        public void setProperties(string field1, string field2){
28            ps.foo = field1;
29            ps.bar = field2;
30        }
31    
32        public void runFunction(){
33            doSomethingWith ps
34        }
35    }
```

Questions about the above structure -

1. At first glance does the use of global variables in this look "improper"? What would be considered "proper" usage of a global variable?
2. Line 9 - If I were to change the form so that field1 & field 2 were public, and instead call `Gloabls.ThisAddIn.setProperties()` and on lines 28 + 29 say `ps.foo = ui.field1.Value;` & `ps.bar = ui.field2.Value;` - *Would that be considered "bad practice"? In what situation would this syntax be applicable?*
3. Line 10 & corresponding functions on lines 27 & 32 - I was thinking of changing the structure to have the `setProperties` function return the `someProperties` struct instead of having it as a global variable, and then using that return value to pass to `runFunction()` like so:

---

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.runFunction(globals.ThisAddIn.setProperties(foo, bar));

public someProperties setProperties(string field1, string field2) {
    someProperties ps = new someProperties();
    ps.foo = field1;
    ps.bar = field2;
    return ps;
}

public void runFunction(someProperties ps){
    doSomethingWith ps;
}
```

Is this structure better than what I currently have? if so, why would it be "bad" to use a global variable in this instance?

Comment: This might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The main time where globals are used properly is if they are a constant, therefore removing the harm of a function changing its value, and not being able to find where that change occurred.
2. If you were to make them public, it *would* be considered bad practice, first reason being they should be properties, not public fields. I would avoid the fields directly, to further preserve the encapsulation.
3. This seems like a better option, though I still believe there is a more practical way to get this affect without globals, that increases encapsulation as well.

**Edit:**

Without knowing much about your program, perhaps something like this:

```
public static class ThisAddInManager
{
    struct someProperties
    {
        public string foo, bar;
    }

    public static var SomeProperties { private get; set; } = new someProperties();
    public static var UI { private get; set; } = new formClass();

    public static void OpenUI() => UI.showDialog();
    public static void RunFunction() => doSomethingWith(SomeProperties);   
}
```

You can learn more about properties [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwGkUxjiDYA)

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of the 'more practical' way for #3? or some pseudo code

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. but what is it called the way you setup `SomeProperties` and `UI`? I've seen that before, and for the most part logically I understand it, but I don't actually know what is going on with them, Like what is the point of `get; set;`?

Comment: Those are called properties. I added a link to a tutorial that I used to learn about them. But consider them sugar for methods like `GetValue` and `SetValue`. With these, we can run functions, methods, and validations, when a field is being `set` or `get`. Also, we can set access modifies, as we did in the answer, so that `get` is `private`, so outside classes can't get its value, they can only set it.

Comment: @Adjit It is syntactic sugar - properties are equivalent to getter and setter functions in other OOP languages.